# Load Models from Autodesk Viewer into Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'd like to (know if it is possible to) load models uploaded via Autodesk free viewer (https://viewer.autodesk.com), into the forge viewer made by following the getting started tutorial (https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/learn/viewer-app/overview).

I have successfully built and ran the tutorial, hence I have a nodejs server which when started let me upload a model and see it in the viewer.
But instead of loading a model everytime, I'd like to access an existing model uploaded via the free viewer - not one stored in a forge bucket. I am assuming to do this I need some way to authenticate to the autodesk viewer and the urn of the model.

Is that even possible, or can I only load forge bucket models?
I tried to use part of the viewer url that looked like a urn without luck.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that’s not exactly possible at the moment because free viewer uses it own app id/secret so it’d not be possible to obtain the access tokens separately.

What I will do is to let Engineering know it’d nice to have the capability to either transfer translated models from the free viewer to your Forge apps or associate/assign credentials to the free viewer with your Forge apps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and suggestion. FYI what I am trying to do is not to need a dedicated server to host models in the app, and instead have people connect to their own repositories.
I would accept your answer but it seems I cannot (yet).

Comment: No you won't need to host the models either after switching to buckets - the derivatives (translated SVFs etc) would be hosted on Forge and can be accessed following the same OAuth flow see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/load-a-model/) and [here](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/) for details.